# Sitemap xml file; Does the url have to end with an ".htm"?

Tags: php, javascript, html, search, .htaccess

I have a website which has **.htaccess** rewrite rules. And alot of them.

This means for example that

```
    www.mydomain.com/classifieds/something_very_very_very_very_Very_very_looong.php?id=12345

    becomes

    www.mydomain.com/classifieds/12345
```

Now, this might be a stupid question, but I must be sure...

I have followed several guides on how to create a good search engine friendly sitemap, and they all have a **`.html or .htm`** at the end of the url adress...
My rewrite-rule uses no such endings, so for me it would have no ending at all.
Will this work as good anyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there's no need for your pages to end with .html.
If you index your pages correctly in sitemap.xml then they should be readable by the web crawler